# Convert from newer sql server to old style ansi sql without join keyword

Tags: sql, join, ansi-sql

We are migrating to a new database platform, [Polyhedra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedra_DBMS) that that is strictly old school ANSI sql without the word 'JOIN'.  Here is what I am trying to do if it were sql server:

```
SELECT A.* FROM tblA A LEFT JOIN tblB B ON A.f1 = B.f1
where B.f1 is NULL
```

I can't seem to recreate where I put the join in the where clause

like:

```
select A.*
from tblA A, tblB B
where A.f1 = B.f1 AND B.f1 is null
```

Obviously, this doesn't return any records even when tblB is empty.  Any idea how to get this done?

Comment: *sigh*, are you saying that the RDBMS that the company is using doesn't allows explicit `JOINS`?, or just that they aren't using those?. If the RDBMS doesn't allow it, why are they using ancient software?, and what is the RDBMS used?

Comment: The RDBMS is part of 3rd party software we are buying.  The database is polyhedra created by ENEA and doesn't support the word join.

Comment: @Bob Run away, far far away!!

Comment: is it ***just*** the keyword of `JOIN` that is not supported, or is the the *concept* of joins that it also not supported? if the former then yuck, if the latter then ...

Comment: I just tried this:select realanalog.name from realanalog,test where realanalog.name = test.node(+);
Error: not implemented: select: outer joins (+)

Comment: @Bob so, basically, that RDBMS doesn't allows outer joins at all?. Then you need to contact your vendor and ask if outer joins are aloowed, and if not, then what is the workaround

Comment: @Lamak The workaround (for outer joins with `JOIN`) is `UNION` and `NOT EXISTS` correlated subqueries (which Bob can only hope for this weird DBMS to support them).

Comment: @ypercube yeah, I know, I was thinking that maybe they have some specific way to do outer joins

Answer (score 3):

Your query doesn't actually require a JOIN at all.

```
SELECT  A.* 
FROM    tblA A 
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblB B WHERE A.f1 = B.f1);
```

I've had a quick flick through the Polyhedra SQL reference manual ([available here](http://developer.polyhedra.com/manuals/rtrdb-reference-manual/sql-reference-manual)), and can't see anything that looks like an equivalent of the `*=` or `(+)` that SQL-Server and Oracle use respectively, I think you might have to resort to something like this for LEFT JOINs where you need the columns (As far as I can tell Polyhedra supports UNION):

```
SELECT  A.f1 AS A, b.f1 AS B
FROM    tblA A, tblB B
WHERE   A.f1 = B.f1
UNION ALL
SELECT  A.f1 AS A, NULL AS B
FROM    tblA A
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblB B WHERE A.f1 = B.f1);
```

[Example on SQL Fiddle (Not in Polyhedra)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21580/2)

**ADDENDUM**

Since `NOT EXISTS` is not allowed, but `NOT IN` is,

```
SELECT  A.f1 AS A, b.f1 AS B
FROM    tblA A, tblB B
WHERE   A.f1 = B.f1
UNION ALL
SELECT  A.f1 AS A, NULL AS B
FROM    tblA A
WHERE   A.F1 NOT IN (SELECT b.F1 FROM tblB B WHERE B.f1 IS NOT NULL);
```

---

There are a number of free DBMS out there, if at all possibile I would **strongly** recommend looking at other vendors.

Comment: Thank you.  I was just going to post that I did this and it worked but clumsy:select realanalog.name from realanalog where name not in (select node from test);

Comment: GarethD answered the question.  Thank you.

Comment: @Bob you can mark this answer as ANSWER :) GarethD will be glad of it :)

Comment: +1 for the 1st query. The 2nd is not correct, for outer joins where columns from both tables are needed, @Bob will have to use `UNION`, if Polyedra supports it.

Comment: @ypercube Good spot, I've added the `UNION` option to the answer.

Comment: Oh my. According to the [Polyhedra SQL manual](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxwb2x5aGVkcmFkYm1zfGd4OjFkMDgxZDQ3NzEyMDJhZjk) `UNION` is supported but not the `EXISTS` keyword (and not even the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses.) My condolences to @Bob.

Comment: Thank you.  I really don't have to do much in it myself.  The vendor has done most of the DB coding and I am glad I didn't have to.  I would have found a better DBMS.  I would imagine tht cost was huge consideration for the vendor.  Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: @GarethD You can remove one `NOT` from `NOT NOT`. Or add one more `NOT` :)

Comment: @ypercube Thanks again. (opted for removing one and not the triple negative)

Answer (score 0):

The old style LEFT OUTER JOIN syntax is (*=)

Try this:

```
select A.*
from tblA A, tblB B
where A.f1 *= B.f1
and B.f1 is null
```

But nowadays it is not ANSI standard and is deprecated as of SQL Server 2005

Comment: I just tried: select realanalog.name from realanalog,test where realanalog.name *= test.node;
Error: syntax error at line 1: select realanalog.name from realanalog,test where realanalog.name *= test.node;
SQL>

Comment: This is technically not true, `*=` is SQL-Server's ANSI 89 LEFT JOIN syntax, it differs by DBMS, eg, Oracle would be `A.f1 = b.f1(+)', unfortunately I am not proficient in deprecated syntax so am unsure of the syntax other DMBS use.

Comment: @GarethD "unfortunately"?, it's a good thing you are not proficient in deprecated syntax

Comment: I just tried this and got error saying outer joins not implemented:select realanalog.name from realanalog,test where realanalog.name = test.node(+);
Error: not implemented: select: outer joins (+)

Comment: @Bob what sort of application is this that would have you writing queries for Polyhedra?

Comment: I don't think that `*=` has anything to do with ANSI/ISO.